# using this code how do you know if sha256 or sha512 would be used?

Tags: go, hash, cryptography

1. Stupid question, in the code below, considering the name is sha512.New512_256, is 512 or 256 used? How do you control which you want? I know I'm missing something elementary here..
2. Also, as I'm looking more at this I'm wondering if hmac is not what I want at all... I'm looking to create some small hashing utilities that will hash any string input or files given as parameters. I would specify the type of hash to use as an input parameter as well... so I would expect the same hash result for the same hash algo used on the same file or string every time... should I be using something else?

thanks

```golang
import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha512"
)

func Hash(tag string, data []byte) []byte {
    h := hmac.New(sha512.New512_256, []byte(tag))
    h.Write(data)
    return h.Sum(nil)
}
```

Comment: https://godoc.org/crypto/sha512#New512_256 Then a quick definition search. It's sha512, that is truncated to 256. Probably just use plain sha512, the concept of generating a sha512 hash and then cutting the tail end of it off just seems cryptographically unsound.

Comment: I stand corrected. Further looking into this, it's not simply chopped off, and sha512 is vulnerable to "length extension attacks", whereas sha512/256 is not "(https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/sha512.html). However, when used in combination with `hmac` it is not vulnerable, so it should be fine.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: Yes, it is simply chopped off.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, not that simply. There is also a domain separation. See, in the answer.

Comment: @kelalaka: Yes, my apologies, you're correct as usual.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear truncating hashes is common practice, and not unsound if done reasonably. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/72685/25107 . One of the properties of a good hash is that every bit of its output is as good as any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA512 is in the SHA-2 families. Variants are listed in [NIST FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf)

```
- SHA-512/256 truncated from SHA-512 with different initial values 
- SHA-512/224 truncated from SHA-512 with different initial values
- SHA-384     truncated from SHA-512 with different initial values
- SHA-512

- SHA-224     truncated from SHA-256 with different initial values
- SHA-256
```

To separate the domains (called **domain separation**) of these hash functions from their truncated version, different initial values are used. Otherwise, an attack on the truncated version can be carried into other versions, v.v.

- ***first question***

With `sha512.New512_256` you actually choose a hash function from `SHA-512` and in this case, it is `SHA-512/256`, You can select the others from the [list](https://godoc.org/crypto/sha512#New512_256) of godoc.org by looking their string.

- ***second question***

You may need `hash` not `hmac`. HMAC is a [keyed hash-based message authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) code and it useful to authenticate with a key. For every time to control the hash (or checksum), you will need the key.

The library, however, uses `Sum512` or `Sum512_256` etc. to calculate the checksum (hash) of a given data. Sample code to calculate the hash is:

```
sha_512 := sha512.New()
sha_512.Write([]byte(input))
hash := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(sha_512.Sum(nil))
```

---

**On Truncation**

At first, the idea of truncation may seem [unsound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241897/using-this-code-how-do-you-know-if-sha256-or-sha512-would-be-used#comment102856156_58241897). Actually it is not. SHA-512 and SHA-256 have [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). However, the truncated versions have [resistances, see table on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions).

It should also be noted that the SHA3 family is designed to have resistance against the length extension attacks. The [capacity prevents](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62624/18298) the attacks.